# MSDeploy SetParameters.xml create empty value

Tags: publish, msdeploy

So my question is relatively simple.

In my Parameters.xml file I have the following line:

```
<parameter name="SEND_TO_FRIEND_BCC" description="Email address of developer" defaultValue="" tags="">
   <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope"\\web.config$" match="/configuration/appsettings/add[@key='SEND_TO_FRIEND_BCC']/@value" />
</parameter>
```

When publish this is creating a file that ends up like this:

```
<setParameter value="" name="SEND_TO_FRIEND_BCC" />
```

When going live, this should replace the current web.config value for SEND_TO_FRIEND_BCC to an empty string.  Instead, when I try an publish I get the following:

```
Error: The 'SEND_TO_FRIEND_BCC" argument cannot be null or empty.
Error count: 1.

   at InRelease.MSDeploy.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have to tell MSDeploy that it is okay for the value to be empty ...

```
<parameter name="SEND_TO_FRIEND_BCC" description="Email address of developer" defaultValue="" tags="">
   <parameterValidation kind="AllowEmpty" />
   <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope"\\web.config$" match="/configuration/appsettings/add[@key='SEND_TO_FRIEND_BCC']/@value" />
</parameter>
```

Comment: How can I directly add this in SetParameters.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

So, by pure chance I tried entering a single empty space and it worked.
If there is a better way I am still eager to learn more...